# Pandas: after slicing along specific columns, get "values" without returning entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is what is happening:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data')

important_region = df[df.columns.get_loc('A'):df.columns.get_loc('C')]

important_region_arr = important_region.values

print(important_region_arr)
```

Now, here is the issue:

```
print(important_region.shape)
output: (5,30)

print(important_region_arr.shape)
output: (5,30)

print(important_region)
output: my columns, in the panda way

print(important_region_arr)
output: first 5 rows of the dataframe
```

How, having indexed my columns, do I transition to the numpy array?

Alternatively, I could just convert to numpy from the get-go and run the slicing operation within numpy. But, how is this done in pandas?

Comment: df[['A','B','C']].head(5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is how you can slice the dataset with specific columns. `loc` gives you access to the grup of rows and columns. The ones before `,` represents rows and columns after. If a `:` is specified it means all the rows.

```
data.loc[:,'A':'C']
```

For more understanding, please look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

Comment: You reference the documentation, however, I arrived at this solution by inspecting the documentation. 

I think what I am referring to is actually a pandas bug, as there is no need to include the row ':' to perform a column-wise slice.  Instead, it seems as if the column-wise slice is passed to numpy when `.values` is called, resulting in a row slice during the conversion. 

This looks right, however, and I will accept.

Comment: @bordeo I see what you are saying. Pandas heavily relies on Numpy. Maybe this was defined for easy interpretation. But thats a good point.